# How to style a check out

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox

I have created a check box and styled it with css3

the problem I'm having is when i duplicate the checkboxes, they dont work, I want to be able to check all or no boxes.

can anyboby assist on this?

[Please see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6Sk/)

```
<form>
        <h2 class="email-me">Email me when...</h2>

    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="notify">
        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
        <label for="notify"></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ID's should be unique.

Comment: I know, but still doesnt work?

Comment: ID's must be unique. See [W3Schools ID and Class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

Comment: @DevlshOne your comment was just negative

Comment: Just looking for some clarity. I also noticed that if you actually put some text in your `label`, it renders it directly onto the stylized checkboxes. What are you going to do to fix that?

Comment: @Bondye Did you actually read the page? It is a good summary of class and ID. [Besides](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182399/can-we-ban-links-to-w3fools-now-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does happen because you use multiple of the same IDs. As commented *a ID should ALWAYS be unique.*

Now you might wonder *but i didn't use the IDs at all?*

Well you actually did. The real problem is that *your checkboxes does not get checked*, thus not get the css effect. This has to do with the `<label for="id">`. Your label respons to your first checkbox, which get clicked.

If you make a unique ID for every `<label>` and checkbox it will work.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5r6Sk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

each checkbox has to have its own unique Id, if you give them all the same id it will see the first one only.

check this it might help in styling http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/

Comment: it is not about the use .. it is about parsing the dom .. Id has to be unique even if you don't use it .. for check and radio box it is part of the functionality.

Comment: If i change the ids the functionality wont work unless i add style to every id. is there another way>

Comment: use class to add style to them, Id for unique function , class used to give group of element the same function or style.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* use unique IDs, whether they're used or not. It's illogical to repeat the same ID twice, it's not an ID if it's not unique.

Your code confuses the dom parser and it won't work.

Try this:

```
<form>
                <h2 class="email-me">Email me when...</h2>

                    <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify1" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify1"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify2" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify2"></label>
                </div>

                    <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify3" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify3"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify4" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify4"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify5" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify5"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify6" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify6"></label>
                </div>









            </form>
```

Note: The label's for="" attribute must match the ID not the name. So they'll need changing to the newly changed ID of the checkbox too as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code a bit. Like this

```
  <form>
                <h2 class="email-me">Email me when...</h2>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify1" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify1"></label>
                </div>

                    <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify2" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify2"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify3" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify3"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify4" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify4"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="notify">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="notify5" name="check" />
                    <label for="notify5"></label>
                </div>
            </form>
```